# Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue Error in postman

Tags: javascript, cookies, postman, coingecko

Im using coingecko price chart api to show chart in app, its working fine , from last week im getting a issue in chart and im tired in postman.
While calling coingecko price chart apicall in postman getting this error but working in web:

url : https://www.coingecko.com/price_charts/486/usd/24_hours.json

[image]

[image]

I have tried passing javascript in apicall.

[image]

how to enable javascript and cookies while apicall in postman and flutter ?